# Pandas pivot_table dropped a column, although no aggregation is done, only reshape

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pivot-table, reshape

Im trying to use Pandas pivot_table function to reshape my data-frame.
But it fails on specific rows and I get the message:

```
FutureWarning: pivot_table dropped a column because it failed to aggregate. This behavior is deprecated and will raise in a future version of pandas. Select only the columns that can be aggregated.
  pivoted = df_first_1000.pivot_table(index=['time', 'motor'], columns='key', values='value')
```

I have data-frame with the culomns: ['time', 'motor','key','value']
and I want to reshape it that the variables in the 'key' column will be columns and the values under 'value' column will be coordinated.

like this, example of the origin df:

```
                        time    motor               key      value
1125 2023-01-02 11:41:10.229  MOTOR_5             state          1
1126 2023-01-02 11:41:10.313  MOTOR_5             right  -8.832798
1127 2023-01-02 11:41:10.313  MOTOR_5              left  -9.093866
1128 2023-01-02 11:41:10.313  MOTOR_5               pos   0.213856
1129 2023-01-02 11:41:10.313  MOTOR_5               vel   0.024477
1130 2023-01-02 11:41:10.314  MOTOR_5              temp  27.969526
1131 2023-01-02 11:41:10.314  MOTOR_5          measured   0.000000
```

after the commands:

```
pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['time', 'motor'], columns='key', values='value')
pivoted.reset_index(inplace=True)
pivoted.columns.name = None
```

I get:

```
                     time    motor     state      measured     pos            left     right       temp       vel
0 2023-01-02 11:41:10.229  MOTOR_5       1.0           NaN       NaN          NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
1 2023-01-02 11:41:10.313  MOTOR_5       NaN           NaN  0.213856      -9.093866    -8.832798   NaN     0.024477
2 2023-01-02 11:41:10.314  MOTOR_5       NaN           0.0       NaN          NaN       NaN       27.969526  NaN
```

I do the same commands in a loop to handle similar data-frames like the origin but its fails and I cannot understand why.
I don't even use the `aggfunc` argument of the `pivot_table`.

example of rows in data-frame id doesn't work:

```
                        time    motor               key      value
1129 2023-01-02 11:41:10.832  MOTOR_6             state          1
1130 2023-01-02 11:41:10.849  MOTOR_6               vol  32.202164
1131 2023-01-02 11:41:10.849  MOTOR_6               vol   32.20553
```

I get:

```
FutureWarning: pivot_table dropped a column because it failed to aggregate. This behavior is deprecated and will raise in a future version of pandas. Select only the columns that can be aggregated.
  pivoted = df_first_1000.pivot_table(index=['time', 'motor'], columns='key', values='value')
                     time    motor
0 2023-01-02 11:41:10.832  MOTOR_6
1 2023-01-02 11:41:10.849  MOTOR_6
```

So I would like to know:

1. Why im getting this warning and it drops the relevant columns?
2. Is there a better way to debug on what rows it fails? (I have a big dataframe and write now im looking for the relevant rows by cutting raws thats work)
3. All I want is to reshape the df's and than compute a few things ' is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

> Why im getting this warning and it drops the relevant columns?

Because `pivot_table` by default aggregate `mean`, so if column `value` is not numeric it raise warning.

Solutions should be:

```
df.pivot(index=['time', 'motor'], columns='key', values='value')

df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')
df.pivot_table(index=['time', 'motor'], columns='key', values='value')
```

> Is there a better way to debug on what rows it fails? (I have a big dataframe and write now im looking for the relevant rows by cutting raws thats work)

You can test which values are not numeric:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').isna() & df['value'].notna()]
```

> All I want is to reshape the df's and than compute a few things ' is there a better way?

If need pivoting seems not. Depends what is *few things*.

Comment: First of all thanks for the respons.
I use ```pivot_table``` instead of ```pivot ``` because I have duplicate entries.
So your solution doesn't work for me , I keep getting the error : 
```raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")```.
In addition my value column is from type float so I dont think this is the problem.
I noticed that in the specific rows it fails its because the entry 'time' is the same, 
How can I ignore it - I dont care its the same , 
only want to reshape the df.

Comment: @user2424097 - So need convert values to numeric?

Comment: did it, same error I get